# Custom date units for javascript

Tags: javascript, time, units-of-measurement

I'm working on a javascript app that does a lot of Date arithmetic, and for convenience (and readable code), I've found it useful to create some constants that I load into each page:

```
var oneSecond = 1000;
var oneMinute = 60*oneSecond;
var oneHour   = 60*oneMinute;
var oneDay    = 24*oneHour;
var oneWeek   = 7*oneDay;
```

I'm going through a code refactor (down with cruft!), and it occurs to me that I can't be the first one who needed constants like these.

Is there an canonical javascript library that provides these (or something comparable) so I can just use it and be nicer to my readers?

Comment: As an aside, constants in js are usually written in ALL_CAPS as a way to differentiate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're looking for datejs:

http://www.datejs.com/